# When should I use ld instead of gcc?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I want to know when I should use `ld` linker instead off `gcc`.

I just wrote a simply hello world in c++, of course I include `iostream` library. If I want make a binary file with `gcc`, I just use: `g++ hello hello.cpp` and I've got my binary file.

Later I try to use `ld` linker. To get object file I use:
`g++ -c hello.cpp`. OK that was easy, but the link command was horrible long:

```
ld -o hello.out  hello.o \
   -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4/ \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4/crtbegin.o \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4/crtend.o \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o \
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o \
   -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lstdc++ -lc
```

I know fact that `gcc` uses the `ld`.
Using `gcc` is better in all cases or just in most cases? Please, tell me something about cases where `ld` linker has advantage.

Comment: Using the linker directly only has an advantage pretty much only when you're not using GCC. Otherwise using `gcc` or `g++` is going to save you a lot of typing and more importantly all the grief involved in figuring out exactly what you need to type and when.

Comment: Thanks, i was afraid about that i didn't notice any helpful usage of ld. Btw u  can use <code>g++ -v -o hello hello.cpp </code> which libraries you need to link. So all functions about link files/liberries, i can set using gcc?

Comment: The problem is that that list of object files, libraries and options will change depending on what GCC options you use, what OS you're using, what version of GCC and potentially other factors. Note that you can link an object file created with GCC by using a command like `gcc -o hello hello.o`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you mentioned, gcc merely acts as a front-end to ld at link time;  it passes all the linker directives (options, default/system libraries, etc..), and makes sure everything fits together nicely by taking care of all these *toolchain-specific* details for you.

I believe it's best to consider the GNU toolchain as a whole, tightly integrated environment (as anyone with an experience of building toolchains for some exotic embedded platforms with, say, dietlibc integration will probably agree).

Unless you have some very specific platform integration requirements, or have reasons not to use gcc, I can hardly think of any advantage of invoking `ld` directly for linking.  Any extra linker-specific option you may require could easily be specified with the `-Wl,` prefix on the gcc command line (if not already available as a plain gcc option).

Comment: In conclusion, ld gives you more control/knowlegde over the files that are linked, I understand correctly?

Comment: It's more a matter of gcc guaranteeing a nice, painless integration (see @RossRidge 's comment about the multiple factors involved).  Any ld option you may need you can still pass through gcc with `-Wl,`.

Answer (score 5):

It is mostly a matter of taste:  you would use `ld` directly when the command-lines are simpler than using `gcc`.  That would be when you are just using the linker to manipulate a small number of shared objects, e.g., to create a shared library with few dependencies.

Because you can pass options to `ld` via the `-Wl` option, often people will recommend just using `gcc` to manage the command-line.

Comment: It's `-wl,` like `gcc test.c -Wl,-verbose` to pass verbose to ld

Comment: Comma **`,`** is a separator, used to separate the option from its value (as well as separating tokens in the option value).  The *option* is `-Wl`.

Answer (score 0):

### In almost all cases, use `gcc` as a linker driver

- The `gcc` driver program does not just call `ld` but also `collect2` to gather information required for a correct binary / startup code.
- `gcc` knows how to use the linker and provides many options: Which startup-code to link, which libraries, which emulation, which multilib variant.  Today, the linker is calling back the compiler by means of a plugin for LTO (link time optimizations) compilations with all the pass-through options so the LTO compiler (`lto1`) will work as desired. You do not want to do that by hand.  A simple `gcc` link passes options worth more than 1200 characters to `ld`. And all depend on profiling (`-p`, `-pg`) relocatable link (`-r`) and whatnot. When you don't want to link a specific part, `gcc` has likely the right option for you: `-nocrt0`, `-nostartfiles`, `-nostdlib`, `-nolibc`, ...

### When to call `ld` directly

As you asked: There are few and rare cases when you want to call `ld` directly.

- You want to find the Binutils version, e.g. `ld -v`.
- You want to find out which options the linker supports, e.g. `ld --help`.  Then use these options to augment a `gcc` invocation with `-Wl` or `-Xlinker`, e.g. to generate a map file  and to define a symbol:

  `gcc ... -Wl,-Map,main.map -Wl,--defsym,my_symbol=0x42`
- You found a bug in `ld` and are preparing a bug report.  Keep it as minimal and self-contained as possible, so that the Binutils people don't have to guess what magic your `gcc` is adding.
- You want to find out about `ld`'s capabilities, e.g. in a `configure` script: Which options does `ld` support, what features etc.  For example in a GCC configure script you cannot call the linker via `gcc` because you are only just building the compiler (`cc1`, `cc1plus`, `lto1`) and `gcc` driver.
- You are writing a test suite for the linker like the Binutils test suite.