# What's the relationship between "gcc linking" and "ld linking"?

Tags: gcc, ld

It's said that linux loader is /usr/bin/ld, but usually we use gcc/g++ to link libraries and executables, we barely use "ld".

The last time I used "ld" manually was when I was learning linux assembly, the only way to generate executable is to ld a .o file to generate executable directly without any library.

My question is, is gcc/g++ containing some function wrappers of "ld", because raw "ld" is too difficult to use? Or we should never use "ld" explicitly for c/c++ program linking, because of blablabla?

Comment: Also see [When i should use ld instead of gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36680470), [Linking C++ code with 'gcc' (without g++)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1001535), and friends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

gcc supplies a few default options to `ld`.

`ld` doesn't know anything about C++, or any other language. `ld` has no idea what libraries your code needs to link with. If you try to link your compiled C++ code with ld directly, it'll bail out on you, since `ld`, by itself, has no idea where it can find `libstdc++`, gcc's C++ runtime library. Do you use strings? vectors? Most of that is template code that gets compiled as part of your object module. But there are a still few precompiled bits, in `libstdc++`, that need to be linked with.

When you give your compiled code to gcc to link, gcc will be courteous enough to pass all your files along to `ld`, and tell `ld` which libraries, in addition to any ones you explicitly specify.

You can link with `ld` directly, if you want to, as long as you specify the same libraries and link option `gcc` uses. But why would you want to do that? Just use gcc to link your gcc-compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't attempt to directly use `ld` to link a C++ program because you need to know the implementation detail of where the static part of the C++ runtime library is located. `g++` knows these implementation details, such as where to find the file `libstdc++.a`. If you tried to use `ld` directly, you would have to supply all these "missing" static libraries.

Comment: Do you mean, even when we default to use libstdc++.so, there's still some content inside libstdc++.a being linked statically into our executable? What are these content doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, is gcc/g++ containing some function wrappers of "ld"

That's right.

> because raw "ld" is too difficult to use?

Well, not really; you could use it yourself without *too* much trouble, but it's convenient to manage the entire build process through a single executable, with a single suite of flags, and often with a single command.

It's also likely that you'd have to provide absolute paths to some runtime libraries (e.g. libstdc++.a) yourself if you bypassed the wrapper (though I haven't tested this).

> Or we should never use "ld" explicitly for c/c++ program linking, because of blablabla?

You're free to do so if you want. The only reason people might raise their eyebrows is to ask why you're not doing it in the conventional manner. If you have a good reason to invoke `ld` directly, rather than going through `g++` and passing through any linker flags that way, then go right ahead!

Comment: then how to do a partial linking with `gcc`?

Comment: @hukeping Sorry, what? If you have a new question, please post it as such with all necessary detail and context.

Comment: Apologise, it's just a response for the last sentence `If you have a good reason to invoke ld directly, rather than going through g++ and passing through any linker flags that way, then go right ahead!` . it seems when you want to some partial linking for example `ld -r -o foobar.o foo.o bar.o` , ld is the best choice.