# Changing Link for make command in linux

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

I am using make command to compile my C programs in linux in vscode terminal, but when I include math.h file in a program it gives me error that functions belonging to the header file is not defined.

Upon reading the error I came to know that the make command is using `ld` instead of `gcc` which seems to solve the problem but how to change this or where its makefile located from where I can change it?

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64.

I have tried removing build essential and then again removing make but it does not seems to link to gcc by default and seems to be stuck with `ld`.

Below is the error:

```
make problem2 
cc     problem2.c   -o problem2
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cciWDsUD.o: in function `distance':
problem2.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: problem2.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: problem2.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: problem2] Error 1
```

Comment: First, please edit your question and format the error messages etc. as code blocks so they are readable.  Second, we can't help you fix your makefile if you don't show us your makefile, or at least show us the rule in your makefile that links your program and leads to the error.  Third, if you want to link a program that uses math functions you have to add the math library to your link line, via `-lm`.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372151/13751442, `gcc` uses `ld` under the hood.

Comment: @MadScientist   hey thank you for your comment, but I cant show my makefile as i dont know where it is stored when i tried to search it gave me a hell lot of makefile in system

Comment: @PeterBergman yes but it properly links the libraries unlike `ld`

Comment: Per the make man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/make,
"Normally you should call your makefile either makefile or Makefile. (We recommend Makefile because it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory listing, right near other important files such as README.) The first name checked, GNUmakefile, is not recommended for most makefiles. You should use this name if you have a makefile that is specific to GNU make, and will not be understood by other versions of make. If makefile is '-', the standard input is read."

Comment: You can probably find the makefile that is used by running `ls` in the directory in which you have been running `make`.

Comment: As above, `make` will look in the current directory where it's invoked, unless you specifically gave it a different place to look.  It won't go looking "everywhere on your system" to find the makefile.  So looking everywhere in your system is not helpful.  Instead, look in the current directory.

Comment: People think `cc` is a C compiler, but it's not, really.  It's really a front-end that can invoke the preprocessor, compiler, assembler, and linker.  You can also run these tools individually, rather than `cc`, but the advantage of using `cc` is that it will add extra arguments to these other tools that lets them work better; if you don't use `cc` then you have to figure out and remember to add all those extra arguments by hand (some compilers have one or more of these tools combined as well).

Comment: @PeterBergman there is no makefile in my current working directory.

Comment: Also when i tried using debugger in vs code with compiler as '/usr/bin/gcc' it sure does give me same error as 'ld' but when using gcc as a command it just complies the file fine