# Fail to create an executable file linking a static library

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linker

In folder `test`, I create `hello.h`,`hello.c`,`main.c`.
My goal is to create a static lib from `hello.h`, `hello.c` and an executable file from the library and `main.c`.
The following is what I have done.

hello.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H  
#define HELLO_H  
void hello(const char* name);  
#endif
```

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
void hello(const char* name){  
    printf("hello %s! \n",name);  
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "hello.h"  
int main(){  
    hello("everyone");  
    return 0;  
}
```

In the terminal (in the `test` folder): I run

```
gcc -c hello.c
ar crv libmyhello.a hello.o // to create a staticlib 
gcc -c main.c
ld -o Cuteee hello.o -lmyhello
>>> ld: cannot find -lmyhello
```

I wonder if anything is wrong?

Comment: The file: `hello.c` needs to have the statement: `#include "hello.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes account of your comments:

> Then I tried ld -o Cuteee main.o -L. -lmyhello but still fails with ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0 ./libmyhello.a(hello.o): In function 'hello': hello.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to 'printf' I am puzzled again.

`gcc` is the GCC tooldriver for compiling and linking C programs.

When you invoke it with options and inputs that signify you want to a compile a C
source file, say `hello.c`, it first invokes the GNU C compiler, `cc1`, to compile `hello.c`
file to a temporary assembly file, say `/tmp/cc8bfSqS.s`. It quietly adds to the compiler commandline
various boilerplate options that are invariant for compiling C
on your system, to spare you the trouble.

Then it invokes the GNU assembler, `as`, to assemble `/tmp/cc8bfSqS.s` to the object file
`hello.o`.

You can pick out all of this from the compilation output if you ask `gcc` to be verbose,
e.g.

```
gcc -v -c hello.c
```

When you invoke `gcc` with options and inputs that signify you want to link
object files and possibly libraries into a program or shared library,
it invokes the GCC internal tool [`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) to do it - which
in turn invokes the system linker `ld` - and `gcc` quietly adds to the commandline
many boilerplate options, libraries and object files that are always
required for linking a C language program or shared library, once again to
spare you trouble.

You have used `gcc` to compile `hello.c` and `main.c` and allowed it to Do The Right
Thing behind the scenes. You haven't attempted to invoke `cc1` and `as` yourself.

But in contrast, when you come to link your program, you haven't used `gcc`; you've
invoked `ld` yourself, without any of the boilerplate additions to the
the commandline that `gcc` would make. That's why the linkage fails.

If you link your program with `gcc` in verbose mode:

```
gcc -v -o Cuteee main.o -L. -lhello
```

you can pick the `collect2` commandline out of the output, something like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/collect2 \
-plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/liblto_plugin.so \
-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper \
-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccgWPdno.res \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
--sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu \
--as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
-pie -z now -z relro -o Cuteee \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o -L. \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib \
-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib \
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../.. \
main.o -lhello -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc \
--as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

All of those options that are passed to `collect2` are passed through to
`ld`. So if you replace `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/collect2` with
`ld` in that monster commandline (or rather the commandline you get on
your own system), you will find that it links your program `./Cuteee`.

That is what linking the program with `gcc` does, over an above:

```
ld -o Cuteee hello.o -lmyhello
```

One of the errors that your linkage attempt fails on:

```
cannot find entry symbol _start
```

is due to the fact that you haven't linked `Scrt1.o` (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o`,
in the commandline above) which contains the C runtime initialization code for
a dynamically linked C program: it defines the symbol `_start`, whose address is the entry point of the program,
to which the loader passes initial control at runtime, and after program initialization
is complete it calls `main`.

The other linkage error:

```
undefined reference to 'printf
```

is due to the fact that you haven't linked the standard C library, `-lc`
(`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`).

Programmers don't link with `ld` directly if they don't have to - e.g.
unless they're targeting an application to a bare-metal environment, and you
can see why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `-L` to let gcc know where to look for your `-l` libraries:

```
gcc -c hello.c
ar crv libmyhello.a hello.o
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o -L. -lmyhello -o Cuteee
```

To create the final executable it's enough to use gcc, ld is not needed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680470/when-i-should-use-ld-instead-of-gcc) in order to understand why you probably don't need to use `ld` specifically.

Comment: But I am curious about how to use ld here(although gcc is better). Then I  tried `ld -o Cuteee main.o -L. -lmyhello` but still fails with     `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0`
`./libmyhello.a(hello.o): In function 'hello':`
`hello.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to 'printf' ` I am puzzled again.

Comment: `printf` is from libc library so you probably need also linking to it using `-lc`.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. corrects several problems in the posted code and in the command line statements.
2. performs the desired operation
3. cleanly compiles/links

And now the proposed changes to the posted code and command line statements:

```
hello.h

#ifndef HELLO_H  
#define HELLO_H  
void hello( const char* );  
#endif
=======================

hello.c:

#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void hello(const char* name)
{  
    printf("hello %s! \n",name);  
}  
========================

main.c:

#include "hello.h"  
int main( void )
{  
    hello("everyone");  
    return 0;  
}  
=========================

In terminal (in test folder):

gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c hello.c -o hello.o -I.
ar crv libmyhello.a hello.o 
=========================

gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c main.c  -o main.o -I.
ld -static main.o -o Cuteee -L. -lmyhello
=========================

./Cuteee
=========================

this should eliminate the error message:
>>> ld: cannot find -lmyhello
```