# C - dynamic linking suceeds but static will not

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am compiling an [example](https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/C/sample.c) for [IUP](https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) graphical toolkit on Linux Debian 10. I downloaded the example and saved it under `main.c`. As you can see if you follow link `#include` preprocessor directives look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iup.h>
```

I wrote a makefile which is used to create dynamicaly linked executable or staticaly linked executable file:

```
#############################################################################################################

dynamic:

    gcc -liup -o dynamic.elf main.c

#############################################################################################################

static: static.o

    ld -e main -o static.elf static.o \
        -l:libiup.a \
        -lgtk-3 \
        -lgdk-3 \
        -lpangocairo-1.0 \
        -lX11 \
        -lcairo \
        -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 \
        -lm \
        -lpango-1.0 \
        -lgobject-2.0 \
        -lglib-2.0 \
        -lpthread \
        -lc

static.o: main.c

    gcc -c -Wall -Wpedantic -o static.o main.c

#############################################################################################################
```

Now If I run make using `make dynamic` the executable is compiled and it works withouth any problem. It is linked to many shared libraries:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ ldd dynamic.elf 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd413cf000)
    libiup.so => /lib/libiup.so (0x00007f4ecb4be000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4ecb2fd000)
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f4ecac0c000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f4ecab10000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4ecab00000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f4eca9e0000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4eca9b8000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4eca96d000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4eca918000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4eca7f9000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f4eca6b8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4eca535000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4ecb85f000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4eca52d000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f4eca31d000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f4eca11a000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f4eca115000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f4ec9f0f000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f4ec9f03000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9ed8000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9ea3000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9e61000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9e57000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f4ec9e52000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9e41000)
    libepoxy.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9d0d000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9b4f000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9a54000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9a3b000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f4ec99f5000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f4ec9939000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9916000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f4ec9911000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f4ec9706000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f4ec96f9000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f4ec94e7000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4ec94db000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f4ec9435000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f4ec93fc000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f4ec93f7000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f4ec93cd000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f4ec93be000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f4ec91b2000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8f94000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f4ec8f89000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f4ec8f6c000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f4ec8f62000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4ec8eec000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4ec8ee7000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f4ec8e94000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f4ec8e60000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8e01000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8bd7000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f4ec8bbd000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f4ec8b90000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8b53000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8b4a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f4ec8944000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f4ec873e000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f4ec8734000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f4ec8693000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f4ec863e000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f4ec8622000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f4ec85fa000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f4ec85db000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f4ec84bd000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f4ec849a000)
```

When I run `make static` it compiles but during execution time program says:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ ./static.elf 
bash: ./static.elf: No such file or directory
```

While program is there and has `+x` rights:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ ls -la | grep static.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ziga ziga 1072080 Mar 30 22:36 static.elf
```

This is how program `static.elf` is linked to shared objects *(`libiup.so` is not present any more as we linked to the static version `libiup.a`)*:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ ldd static.elf 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc73500000)
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f17f7e4d000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f17f7d51000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f7d41000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f17f7c00000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f17f7ae0000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f7aba000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f17f7935000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f78ea000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f7895000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f7776000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f17f7755000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f17f7594000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f758c000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f17f737c000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f17f7179000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f17f7174000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f17f6f6e000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f17f6f62000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f6f37000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f6f02000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f17f6ec0000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f17f6eb6000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f17f6eb1000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f17f6ea0000)
    libepoxy.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f17f6d6c000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f6bae000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f17f6ab3000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f17f6a9a000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f17f6a54000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f17f6998000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f17f6991000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f17f6786000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f17f6779000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f17f6567000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f17f655d000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f17f6531000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f17f652c000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f17f6486000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f17f644d000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f17f6448000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f17f6439000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f17f622d000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f17f600f000)
    /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f17f8576000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f17f6004000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f17f5fe7000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f17f5fdd000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f17f5f67000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f17f5f14000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f17f5ee0000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f17f5e81000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f17f5c59000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f17f5c3d000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f17f5c10000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f17f5bd3000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f17f5bca000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f17f59c6000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f17f57be000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f17f57b4000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f17f5713000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f17f56be000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f17f56a4000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f17f567a000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f17f565b000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f17f553d000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f17f551a000)
```

If anyone can tell me what I am missing here in order to run the program I would be very happy. I want to use `ld` separately.

---

As suggested I am adding output from `strace`:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ strace ./static.elf 
execve("./static.elf", ["./static.elf"], 0x7ffcb3bec860 /* 31 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: exec: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

and `readelf`:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:2020-03-26--example-a$ readelf -a static.elf | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld64.so.1]
```

---

### Solution - but not exactly what I want

The working makefile section for staticaly linking is this one:

```
gcc main.c -o static.elf -Wl,-Bstatic -liup -Wl,-Bdynamic \
    -lc \
    -lgtk-3 \
    -lgdk-3 \
    -lpangocairo-1.0 \
    -lX11 \
    -lcairo \
    -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 \
    -lm \
    -lpango-1.0 \
    -lgobject-2.0 \
    -lglib-2.0 \
    -lpthread
```

but it does not use `ld` and I want to know why `ld` fails to link...

Comment: Why are you using `ld` directly?  Why not just use `gcc` front-end?  I'm sure that it's doing something that the `ld` command is not that makes this work.  If you can't get it to work, I recommend running something like `strace ./static.elf` and see what it says.

Comment: I like using `ld` separately because of clarity and because I usualy include `ld` scripts for embedded targets like this. Also this does not work if I use `gcc` directly. I added the information that `strace` returns.

Comment: what does `readelf -a static.elf | grep interpreter` say?

Comment: Also, there's nothing like "clarity" with using `ld` directly. `gcc` knows how to pass it a lot of necessary switches (eg. on many systems only PIE executables are supported).

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, `main` is NOT the default entry point, and your "static" executable is obviously not statically linked.

Comment: Almost no program is entirely staticaly linked using `-static`... I wanted only to staticaly link `libiup.a` which is in fact the only `.a` file that I have. Others are `.so` which is common for Linux distributions.

Comment: You can just pass the `libiup.a` library as an argument on the command line `gcc main.c libiup.a ...`. Or `gcc main.o libiup.a ...` usink gcc as the final linker.

Comment: Everyone already said everyting, but I'll just add: there's absolutely no reason you can't pass a linker script, or _any other_ linker option, through `gcc`.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gcc` to link and use `-Wl,-Bstatic` to tell the linker to prefer linking against static libraries rather than shared ones. Example:

```
gcc main.c -o static.elf -Wl,-Bstatic -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 ...
```

You can also selectively link against only some libraries statically by using `-Wl,-Bdynamic`:

```
gcc main.c -o static.elf -Wl,-Bstatic -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lX11 ...
```

This will link against the X11 shared library, but link gtk and gdk statically. You can switch between `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` as often as you want.

Finally, note that if a library only provides an `.a` file but no `.so`, then you don't actually need to use `-Wl,-Bstatic`. The linker will automatically statically link the `.a` file since it's the only choice.

Comment: This approach worked... But what I want to know is why doesn't `ld` suceed?

Comment: You didn't pass `ld` the right elf interpreter, and it ended up using `/lib/ld64.so.1`, which doesn't exist on your system. You were also passing `ld` `main` as the entry point, which would've cause it to crash, but it didn't even reach that point ;-)

Comment: @71GA It's a low-level tool not supposed to be used directly by humans. As mosvy said, you also need to link against the correct loader/interpreter. Just use `gcc` instead, as it knows how to call `ld` correctly.

Comment: @mosvy Can you explain a bit more. I don't quite understand why it used `/lib/ld64.so.1`... @NikosC. I always have to use `ld` when I compile for embedded targets.

Comment: Because that was the ld's default, which gcc overrides via command line switches (eg. `-I`, `--dynamic-linker`) or some linker script when calling it. gcc is also pasing the crt*.o start files, where ld could find the right entry point (`_start`).

Comment: @mosvy I expected that it supplies startup files but did not know it passes other parameters. I would like to know exactly what is going on here...

Comment: I come from electronics field and there we have a lot of speciffic systems which demand special linking parameters so we use linker scripts in order to reorder parts of a programs so that everything is on addresses where MCPU expects it to be *(imagine a punch card)*. Also often we combine assembler source files *(we assemble these with `arm-none-eabi-as -c`)* & C source files *(we compile with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c ...`)* to get objects, and then we need `arm-none-eabi-ld ...` to link objects into executable... So it is impossible to avoid linker there...

Comment: ... but in embedded world we don't deal with mainstream operating systems which need **large amount** of link parameters! So linker is not as hard to use in embeddeed! But the story is completely different if you want to write programs for mainstreem operating systems...

Comment: ... I just now learned thanks to you that different mainstream operating systems need vastly different link parameters and to guess theese is almost impossible... This is why if we compile for mainstream operating systems we use `gcc` directly and avoid `ld`, because gcc automaticaly sets the right parameters for the operating system for which `gcc` itself was compiled. This is a nice reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680470/when-i-should-use-ld-instead-of-gcc

Comment: Well anyway. Instead of `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` I decided to use `-dn` *(dynamic no)* and `-dy` *(dynamic yes)* which do exactly the same but are a shorter version.

Comment: @71GA On most (all?) modern ELF-based Unix systems, the compiler will generate a dynamically linked executable by default, so the safest way out is pass (or omit) the `-static` option to gcc -- BOTH when compiling AND when linking. If you want to pass arguments directly to `ld`, you should use the `-Wl,link-opt,arg` switch of gcc, as already shown in this answer (eg. `-Wl,-e,funcname` to override the default `_start` entry point). The way the gcc driver program calls other subprograms is pretty involved, you can have a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html#Spec-Files)